# Flex 4.0 TabBar remove tabs and content

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, tabbar

I have a `TabBar`, and on CTRL+ALT+Click (on the close button), I want to close all of the tabs, and remove their content.

Adding event listeners on each tab's exit button:

```
    public static var CONTROL_PRESSED:Boolean = false;
    public static var ALT_PRESSED:Boolean = false;
this.tabBar.addEventListener(ChildExistenceChangedEvent.CHILD_ADD, function(event:ChildExistenceChangedEvent):void{
            var tab:SuperTab = SuperTab(event.relatedObject);
            tab.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, function(event:FlexEvent):void{
                for(var i:int = 0; i < tab.numChildren; i+=1){
                    if(tab.getChildAt(i) is Button){
                        var exitButton:Button = Button(tab.getChildAt(i));

                        exitButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function(event:MouseEvent):void{
                            if(event.altKey){
                                ALT_PRESSED = true;
                            }else{
                                ALT_PRESSED = false;
                            }
                            if(event.ctrlKey){
                                CONTROL_PRESSED = true;
                            }else{
                                CONTROL_PRESSED = false;
                            }
                        }, false, 1000);
                        model.tabExitButtonArray.push(exitButton);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

I have tried:

1. Iterating through the array of exit buttons and dispatching a mouse down event on each of them. This does nothing.

   ```
   var customEventObject:MouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mouseDown");
   customEventObject.ctrlKey = true;
   customEventObject.altKey = true;
   for(var i:int = 0; i< model.tabExitButtonArray.length; i++){
       var b:Button = model.tabExitButtonArray[i];
       b.dispatchEvent(customEventObject);
   }
   ```
2. Removing tab bar child elements, but it only removes the tabs themselves

   ```
   model.tabBar.removeAllChildren();
   ```
3. Change tab bar selected index and remove each tab the way I would remove a single tab. This removes the first current tab.

   ```
           for(var i:int = 0; i< model.tabExitButtonArray.length; i++){
           model.tabBar.selectedIndex = i;

           Class.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(object, function));
       }
   ```
4. reset dataProvider and remove children

   ```
       model.tabBar.removeAllChildren();
       model.tabBar.dataProvider = new Array();
   ```

Comment: Did you try removing the dataprovider?

Comment: @FlorianLavorel , what way would I go about that? `dataProvider = new Array();`?